# Add Section to Shopify theme programmatically

Tags: shopify

I have a Shopify app and would like to add it to Shopify as dynamic section programmatically. I know how to do it manually.

Basically i create .liquid file in sections in theme code editor. 
Here is short tutorial for adding dynamic sections: https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/how-to-create-your-first-shopify-theme-section

But i would like to achieve the same result programmatically, i.e via some API call.

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, but the related API is in preview mode still and is not advised to be used in production environments.

> Caution During the preview phase we will be making changes to the
>   sections API based on your feedback. This may cause invalid theme code
>   or page data to be present in preview shops. As the API is iterated
>   upon, we will clean up existing data and theme code on beta-flagged
>   preview shops, which may result in data loss. Changes will be
>   communicated and documentation will be updated.
>
> During the preview phase, the theme editor may not function properly
>   on section-enabled pages.

That being said, have a look at [Section Theme Rest API](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/online-store/section-themes). Specifically, you will need to work with [Sections Property](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/online-store/section-themes#the-sections-property).

Answer (score 0):

Liquid is a server side rendering language, this means you can not re-render on realtime. but you could render your code and hide it with display: none; and using axios or ajax after calling your API show that section.